# Automatically Backup MySQL database on linux server

Tags: mysql, linux, backup

I need a script that automatically makes a backup of a MySql Database. I know there are a lot of posts and scripts out there on this topic already but here is where mine differs.

1. The script needs to run on the machine hosting the MySql database (It is a linux machine).
2. The backups must be saved onto the same server that the database is on.
3. A backup needs to be made every 30 minutes.
4. When a backup is older than a week it is deleted unless it is the very first backup created that week. i.e out of these backups backup_1_12_2010_0-00_Mon.db, backup_1_12_2010_0-30_Mon.db, backup_1_12_2010_1-00_Mon.db ... backup_7_12_2010_23-30_Sun.db etc only backup_1_12_2010_0-00_Mon.db is kept.

Anyone have anything similar or any ideas where to start?

Comment: **NEVER** place backup in the production machine. If your production server die, you back-up also gone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doing pretty much the same like many people.

1. The script needs to run on the machine hosting the MySql database (It is a linux machine).
   => Create a local bash or perl script (or whatever) "myscript" on this machine "A"
2. The backups must be saved onto the same server that the database is on.
   => in the script "myscript", you can just use **mysqldump**. From the local backup, you may create a **tarball** that you send via **scp** to your remote machine. Finally you can put your backup script into the **crontab** (crontab -e).

Some hints and functions to get you started as I won't post my entire script, it does not fully do the trick but not far away :

```
#!/bin/sh
...
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"   
FILE="$LOCAL_TARBALLS/$TARBALL/mysqldump_$db-$SNAPSHOT_DATE.sql"  
$MYSQLDUMP -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS $db > $FILE && $GZIP $GZ_COMPRESSION_LEVEL $FILE   

function create_tarball()
{
local tarball_dir=$1
tar -zpcvf $tarball_dir"_"$SNAPSHOT_DATE".tar.gz" $tarball_dir >/dev/null
return $?
}

function send_tarball()
{
local PROTOCOLE_="2"
local IPV_="4"
local PRESERVE_="p"
local COMPRESSED_="C"
local PORT="-P $DESTINATION_PORT"
local EXECMODE="B"

local SRC=$1
local DESTINATION_DIR=$2
local DESTINATION_HOST=$DESTINATION_USER"@"$DESTINATION_MACHINE":"$DESTINATION_DIR

local COMMAND="scp -$PROTOCOLE_$IPV_$PRESERVE_$COMPRESSED_$EXECMODE $PORT $SRC $DESTINATION_HOST &"

echo "remote copy command: "$COMMAND
[[ $REMOTE_COPY_ACTIVATED = "Yes" ]] && eval $COMMAND

}
```

Then to delete files older than "date", you can look at **man find** and focus on the **mtime** and **newer** options.

Edit: as said earlier, there is no particular interest in doing a local backup except a temproray file to be able send a tarball easily and delete it when sent.

Answer (score 25):

*Answer*: A cron

*Description*:

Try creating a file something.sh with this:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 mysqldump -u root -p pwd --opt db1.sql > /respaldosql/db1.sql
 mysqldump -u root -p pwd --opt db2.sql > /respaldosql/db2.sql
 cd /home/youuser/backupsql/
 tar -zcvf backupsql_$(date +%d%m%y).tgz *.sql
 find -name '*.tgz' -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Give the adequate permission to the file

```
 chmod 700 mysqlrespaldo.sh
```

or

```
 sudo chmod 700 something.sh
```

and then create a cron with

```
 crontab -e
```

setting it like

```
 **0 1 * * *** /home/youruser/coolscripts/something.sh
```

Remember that the numbers or '*' characters have this structure:

> ```
> Minutes (range 0-59)
> Hours (0-23)
> Day of month (1-31)
> Month (1-12)
> Day of the week (0-6 being 0=Domingo)
> Absolute path to script or program to run
> ```

You can also use the helper folder available in newer versions of linux distros, where you find `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.weekly`, etc. In this case, you can create a symlink to your script into the chosen folder and OS will take charge of running it with the promised recurrence (from a powerful comment by @Nick).

Comment: I would actually drop the script (or a symlink to it) in one of the /etc/cron.daily folder if your distro supports it instead of specifically adding a line to the master crontab.

Answer (score 10):

Create a shell script like the one below:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -u username -p'password' dbname > /my_dir/db_$(date+%m-%d-%Y_%H-%M-%S).sql
find /mydir -mtime +10 -type f -delete
```

Replace username, password and your backup directory(my_dir). Save it in a directory(shell_dir) as filename.sh

Schedule it to run everyday using crontab -e like:

```
30 8 * * * /shell_dir/filename.sh
```

This will run everyday at 8:30 AM and backup the database. It also deletes the backup which is older than 10 days. If you don't wanna do that just delete the last line from the script.

Answer (score 8):

You can do most of this with a one-line cronjob set to run every 30 minutes:

```
mysqldump -u<user> -p<pass> <database> > /path/to/dumps/db.$(date +%a.%H:%M).dump
```

This will create a database dump every 30 minutes, and every week it'll start overwriting the previous week's dumps.

Then have another cronjob that runs once a week that copies the most recent dump to a separate location where you're keeping snapshots.

Answer (score 3):

After a brief reading the question and the good answers i would add few more points. Some of them are mentioned already.

**The backup process can involve next steps:**

1. Create a backup
2. Compress the backup file
3. Encrypt the compressed backup
4. Send the backup to a cloud (DropBox, OneDrive, GoogleDrive, AmazonS3,...)
5. Get a notification about results
6. Setup a schedule to run the backup process periodically
7. Delete the old backup files

To compound a script to cover all the backup steps you need an effort and knowledge.

I would like to share a [link to an article](https://sqlbak.com/blog/how-to-automate-mysql-database-backups-in-linux) (i'm one of the writers) which describes the **most used ways to backup MySQL databases** with some details:

1. Bash script

   ```
    # Backup storage directory  
    backup_folder=/var/backups

    # Notification email address 
    recipient_email=<username@mail.com>

    # MySQL user
    user=<user_name>

    # MySQL password
    password=<password>

    # Number of days to store the backup 
    keep_day=30 

    sqlfile=$backup_folder/all-database-$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S).sql
    zipfile=$backup_folder/all-database-$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S).zip 

    # Create a backup 
    sudo mysqldump -u $user -p$password --all-databases > $sqlfile 

    if [ $? == 0 ]; then
       echo 'Sql dump created' 
    else
       echo 'mysqldump return non-zero code' | mailx -s 'No backup was created!' $recipient_email  
       exit 
    fi 

    # Compress backup 
    zip $zipfile $sqlfile 

    if [ $? == 0 ]; then
       echo 'The backup was successfully compressed' 
    else
       echo 'Error compressing backup' | mailx -s 'Backup was not created!' $recipient_email 
       exit 
    fi 

    rm $sqlfile 

    echo $zipfile | mailx -s 'Backup was successfully created' $recipient_email 

    # Delete old backups 
    find $backup_folder -mtime +$keep_day -delete
   ```
2. Automysqlbackup

   ```
    sudo apt-get install automysqlbackup
    wget https://github.com/sixhop/AutoMySQLBackup/archive/master.zip

    mkdir /opt/automysqlbackup
    mv AutoMySQLBackup-master.zip 
    cd /opt/automysqlbackup
    tar -zxvf AutoMySQLBackup-master.zip

    ./install.sh

    sudo nano /etc/automysqlbackup/automysqlbackup.conf

    CONFIG_configfile="/etc/automysqlbackup/automysqlbackup.conf"
    CONFIG_backup_dir='/var/backup/db'
    CONFIG_mysql_dump_username='root'
    CONFIG_mysql_dump_password='my_password'
    CONFIG_mysql_dump_host='localhost'
    CONFIG_db_names=('my_db')
    CONFIG_db_exclude=('information_schema')
    CONFIG_mail_address='mail@google.com'
    CONFIG_rotation_daily=6
    CONFIG_rotation_weekly=35
    CONFIG_rotation_monthly=150

    automysqlbackup /etc/automysqlbackup/automysqlbackup.conf
   ```
3. Third party tools

Hope it would be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

My preference is for [AutoMySQLBackup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/) which comes with Debian. It's really easy and creates daily backups, which can be configured. As well, it stores on weekly and then one monthly backup as well.

I have had this running for a while and it's super easy to configure and use!

Answer (score 0):

You might consider this Open Source tool, matiri, https://github.com/AAFC-MBB/matiri which is a concurrent mysql backup script with metadata in Sqlite3. Features (more than you were asking for...):

- Multi-Server: Multiple MySQL servers are supported whether they are co-located on the same or separate physical servers.
- Parallel: Each database on the server to be backed up is done separately, in parallel (concurrency settable: default: 3)
- Compressed: Each database backup compressed
- Checksummed: SHA256 of each compressed backup file stored and the archive of all files
- Archived: All database backups tar'ed together into single file
- Recorded: Backup information stored in Sqlite3 database

Full disclosure: original matiri author.